# MySQL query not working in PHP, but works perfectly in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

```
$double = "DELETE tr1 FROM track AS tr1 
  INNER JOIN track AS tr2 
  WHERE tr1.id > tr2.id 
  AND tr1.idm = tr2.idm 
  AND tr1.k1b = tr2.k1b 
  AND tr1.data = tr2.data 
  AND tr1.st = '' 
  AND tr2.st = 'Ready' 
  AND tr1.k1b NOT LIKE '' 
  AND tr2.k1b NOT LIKE '' 
  AND tr1.usun LIKE '' 
  AND tr2.dubel LIKE '1'";

$dubsr = mysql_query($double) or die (mysql_error());
```

Works in phpmyadmin, in PHP not working, mysql_error() is empty.

I'll be grateful for advice.

PS. I've tried putting "data" keyword in backsticks like any other variables and still nothing.

Comment: The `mysql` extension is obsolete (it has been deprecated for over a decade, and was removed in PHP 7), you should be using `mysqli` or `PDO`.

Comment: A) Can you run *any* queries, like even `SELECT 1`?

Comment: @tadman - all other queries are working fine

Comment: When it's "not working" either it runs successfully and gives you a result, or it doesn't and it produces an error. There is no middle ground. Inspect the result in `$dubsr`.

Comment: Error string is empty, launching query is not affecting any action. Nothing happens, no feedback. When I launch query directly in phpmyadmin it deletes the result

Comment: What is `$dubstr` after the operation? Use `var_dump()` to find out. Keep a very close eye on your server error log while testing.

Comment: Maybe you are not connecting to the same database?

Comment: var_dump() is NULL